# Función muestra error: número invalido de parámetros (Invalid parameter number)

Tags: php, mysql, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Me tira un error de número de parámetros. En qué me estoy equivocando?

El error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Acá dejo la función que utilizo:

```
ProductosModel->aumentar(1, '0.1')
```

```
public function aumentarPrecio()
    {
        $id=$_POST['categoria'];
        $porcentaje=$_POST['aumentar_precio'];
        $porciento=$porcentaje/100;
        $data= $this->model->aumentar($porciento,$id);
        if($data == 1){
            $msg=array('msg'=>'Precios actualizados','icono'=>'success');

        }else{
            $msg=array('msg'=>'Error al reingresar el producto','icono'=>'error');

        }
        echo json_encode($msg, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        die();
    }
```

Acá esta el `update` a la base de datos:

```
    public function aumentar(string $porciento,int $id)
    {
        $sql="UPDATE productos set precio_compra=precio_compra+(precio_compra*$porciento) where id_categoria=$id";
       $datos=array($porciento);
        $data=$this->save($sql,$datos);
        if ($data == 1) {
            $res = "modificado";
        }else{
            $res = "error";
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Hice la inserción normal en `mysql` en prueba para verificar  y salió bien, pero cuando paso los parámetros me sale ese error. Los datos que estoy pasando están bien.

Comment: Amigo te olvidaste de mostrarnos el error que te sale

Comment: ahi  te lo edite

Comment: Te esta diciendo que (aumentar) espera mas parámetros de los que recibe o que recibe mas parámetros de los necesarios, busca donde tienes definido (aumentar) y verifica que espere 2 parámetros.

Comment: En el segundo parámetro que está recibiendo la función, te está llegando '0.1', según lo indicas acá `ProductosModel->aumentar(1, '0.1')` y está esperando un entero `int $id`. Luego en el `update` estás tratado de hacer esto: `id_categoria='0.1'` lo cual no parece ser muy lógico.